# Unable to add ssl certificate to microsoft power apps

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, powerapps, pem, pfx

I bought a wildcard ssl certificate with Combell which I need to install in my Microsoft Power App. Combell uses AES-256 encryption and Microsoft want 3DES so I downloaded the .pem file and converted it to a .pfx with 3DES encryption with this openssl command:

```
openssl  pkcs12 -keypbe PBE-SHA1-3DES -certpbe PBE-SHA1-3DES -export -in  my_encrypted_pem.pem -out my_new_pkcs12.pfx -name “my-name”
```

So now I have a pfx certificate file, and it uses the 3DES encryption that Microsoft wants.
[Microsoft requirements for ssl certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/portals/admin/manage-ssl-certificates#ssl-certificate-requirements)

And still I can't upload the certificate in my admin center, it tells me that the password is incorrect or that the encryption used by the certificate is not supported  (It's in Dutch but see image with error here: [link to img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDdtQ.png))

Don't know what's the problem because the password is 100% correct and the encryption used is 3DES. Can someone please help

Comment: I'll guess you're using OpenSSL 3.0.x although you don't say so, because that's the only version that defaults pkcs12 encryption to PBES2/AES; 3.0.x also changes the MAC hash to sha256 and it's possible MS dislikes that even though their doc doesn't say so: try adding `-macalg sha1`. (PS: your image link doesn't work for me, I get a login page for appsaloon)

Comment: Hi @dave_thompson_085 thanks for your reply. And yes I'm using OpenSSL 3.0.2. In the requirements Microsoft says:
"Be SHA2-enabled; SHA1 support is being removed from popular browsers."
But the MAC hash is something else then?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thank you this worked. you can post it as an answer